# Remove subquery from JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

In the following query, I would like the remove the subquery from the `JOIN` statement (since my two `SELECT` statements are selecting data from same table). How can I use that alias? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
declare @StartDate datetime= '8/01/2011'
declare @EndDate datetime = '9/20/2011'
declare @PortfolioId int = 6

SELECT
   Previous.PreviousNAV,
   Todays.TodaysNAV,
   ISNULL((Todays.TodaysNAV-Previous.PreviousNAV),0) NetChange,
   ISNULL((Todays.TodaysNAV-Previous.PreviousNAV) / Todays.TodaysNAV,0) BAMLIndex
FROM
(
   SELECT PortfolioId,ISNULL(NAV,0) PreviousNAV
   FROM Fireball..NAV
   WHERE Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate and PortfolioId = @PortfolioId
) Previous
JOIN
(
   SELECT PortfolioId,ISNULL(NAV,0) TodaysNAV
   FROM Fireball..NAV
   WHERE Date = @EndDate and PortfolioId = @PortfolioId
) Todays
ON Previous.PortfolioId = Todays.PortfolioId
```

Comment: I don't really understand your query. In your `Previous` table you are including the same PortfolioId than in your `Todays`table, since you are using a `BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just eliminate the subqueries entirely.  I don't think they add anything to the query.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT
   Previous.NAV as PreviousNAV,
   Todays.NAV as TodaysNav,
   ISNULL((Todays.NAV-Previous.NAV),0) NetChange,
   ISNULL((Todays.NAV-Previous.NAV) / Todays.NAV,0) BAMLIndex
FROM
    Fireball..NAV as Previous
JOIN
    Fireball..NAV as Todays
    ON Previous.portfolioID = Todays.PortfolioID
WHERE Previous.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
    AND Previous.PortfolioId = @PortfolioId
    AND Todays.Date = @EndDate
```

Comment: thank you can you please give me some good threads to learn SQL